# Fade banner using HTML and CSS works in all browser except Internet Explorer (all version)

Tags: html, css

The animated banner just doesn't show in IE. It works perfectly in all browser. Need advice to fix this problem. I want to avoid js and want to use only CSS and HTML for coding. Ever after giving prefix for browser it is not working in IE.

```css
@keyframes fader {
  0% {
    background: url(images/1Frame300x180.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  25% {
    background: url(images/2Frame300x180.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  50% {
    background: url(images/3Frame300x180.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  75% {
    background: url(images/4Frame300x180.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
  100% {
    background: url(images/1Frame300x180.png);
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

#wrapper {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 250px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#gallery {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: skyblue;
  -webkit-animation: fader 12s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fader 12s infinite;
  -o-animation: fader 12s infinite;
  -ms-animation: fader 12s infinite;
  animation: fader 12s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="gallery">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/180" alt="" style="width: 100%; opacity: 0;" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/logo300x70.png" alt="" style="width:100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with images from for example placeholder.com

Comment: I am sorry i am new on this site. where do i get snippet? I clicked on run code snippet option but nothing appeared

Comment: I clicked edit and then the button with `[<>]` - you scroll down and click edit above snippet and add relevant missing object and code

Comment: Let me just upload the entire html and css file. I hope it will be ok with you to rectify the error.

Comment: I tried. Its not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Warning! This CSS3 code will only work on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and maybe newer versions of IE (after version 9)

Since IE9 doesn’t support css3 animations but does support opacity: 0; property you will have to have ie9 load a separate ie9 css where you have all your fade classes set to opacity: 1

you should try this :

```
#gallery{
       -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
       -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
        animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: Where do i add the images?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Change your `0%` to `0.001%`

I think the problem has something to do with your keyframes at 0% and IE doing something funny about where it starts the animation

Comment: Tried. Not working. Earlier nothing was showing in the animated box, but after changing the value to 0.001% the skyblue color comes and fades but no images.